# Unity WebGL Canvas only loads on select machines

Tags: unity, javascript, webgl, browser-based-games

https://herbertjoseph.com

There is a WebGL build in the background of this site, and it doesn't seem to laod on my iPad. I've asked a few people to visit and check it out, and some have said that the scene doesn't load on their workstations either...

I've checked the console of the builds, and found no egregious errors. Most browsers, even mobile, support webgl now...

How can I ensure it'll work across most/all devices?

Comment: Did you use any particular tools or templates to generate this web page HTML or embedding javascript?

Comment: https://imgur.com/GP0BxG9.png "failed to asynchronously prepare wasm: Error: Out of executable memory in function at index 25394"

Comment: @DMGregory, I am using react-unity-webgl to render the canvas, but this was an issue before using it. The bar would load near completion then stop. but the comment above seems to highlight the reason

Comment: Sounds like that comment should be edited in as part of your question then.